# XSL test on a set of nodes?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have a set of "file" nodes with a type attribute

```
<files>
    <file type="main">asdf</file>
    <file type="main_en">asdf</file>
    <file type="main_fr">asdf</file>
    <file type="pdf">asdf</file>
</files>
```

How do I check on the set of files if one of the nodes has at least 1 attribute that starts with "main".
I was thinking something like:

```
<xsl:when test="contains(string(files/file[@type]),'main')">
```

But all the functions or tests I know seem to only be for a specific node and not a set of nodes.
I would rather avoid using a for each type solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:when test="files/file[contains(@type, 'main')]">
```

Or, even better:

```
<xsl:when test="files/file[starts-with(@type, 'main')]">
```

Comment: Hmm, don't know how this was upvoted... I was checking the name of the attribute instead of its value! Fixing.

Comment: I tried this and it gave me this error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: For extension function, could not find method org.apache.xpath.objects.XNodeSet.startsWith([ExpressionContext,] #STRING).

Comment: Interesting - I have no idea why you would get that error, but after reviewing the xpath that resulted from my first fix, it was still a little complicated. I just fixed that, but no idea whether it will address the error you described - I'm afraid I don't have a Xalan environment to play with.

Comment: Compared to Dimitre's answer it would be that adding a / in front of files would make it the same except more specific. And that works, but it returns false for some reason. `<xsl:when test="/files/file[starts-with(@type, 'main')]">`

Comment: Oh .. it was my bad.. I was using fn:starts-with vs starts-with .. didn't think it would make a difference. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

> How do I check on the set of files if
>   one of the nodes has at least 1
>   attribute that starts with "main".

**Use**:

```
boolean(/*/file[@*[starts-with(., 'main')]])
```

This evaluates to `true()` exactly when there is at least one `file` element that is a child of the top element of the XML document and that has at least one attribute, whose string value starts with the string `"main"`

**When used in a `test` attribute (of `<xsl:if>` or `<xsl:when>`) or as a predicate, the reference to the `boolean()` function is not necessary and may be omitted**:

```
/*/file[@*[starts-with(., 'main')]]
```

Comment: For some reason it's returning false when I try this.

Comment: I was thinking if there is a way I can concat all the types with a delimiter into a variable and just do a contains($var,'main'). But im not sure how to do that.

Comment: Yeah I was using fn:starts-with instead of starts-with .. didn't think it would make a difference. Thanks :)

Comment: @Jaycuse: Glad that you found the reason for your problem. Maybe it is time to consider accepting the best answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know your real purpose, but this example might help you:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/files">
        <xsl:if test="file[contains(@type,'main')]">
            There is at least one file element with 'main' in @type
        </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In the end I just want the code in the if to run once. That's why I want to avoid a for each. Because it would run 3 times. Kind of like if there is at least one main file. Do this once, otherwise do this once.